# How to Reduce the Offset between the Y-Axis and Lines in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly

I created a simple **Python 3.X** script with **Matplotlib** which creates a linear function and draws it to the figure.

So far I just couldn't figure out how to **remove the white space / offset** between the y-Axis and the lines / plots from the figure window.

See this simple example. The red arrow points down to the giant space between the beginning of the lines and the y-Axis.

[OFFSET EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlzC5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the max limit of y axis by adding

```
plt.ylim(0, 8)
```

Comment: worked but now the x-axis goes to 400 but in 50-steps -> 0 - 50 - 100 - 150 ... How can I change that, it worked with xticks but that one causes the offset issue.

Comment: the question marked by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest has all the answer you need to solve the offset and x&y label issues. I recommend everyone to check that one's answer out!